# how to set materialButton icon to the center

Tags: android, android-button, material-components

I am using **supportLibrary = "28.0.0-beta01"** version.
Here is my code in .xml file:

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_my_orders"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

To my code icon of the drawable locating left side of the button. I want to set button to the center.
*I want to achieve this result*
[image]

---

### Edit

I don't need to any custom views or hard coded things. If this is a bug (app:iconGravity), I will wait next release.

### EDIT

The bug fixed in the version **28.0.0-rc01**,just change the version.

Comment: so currently what is happening >

Comment: Wrap your `MaterialButton` inside another `LinearLayout`  and  make your `MaterialButton` width to `wrap_content`

Comment: @MuhammadakbarRafiqov Which library you are using for it,i used implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' but i am not getting option of Materialbutton

Comment: @MuhammadakbarRafiqov use `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and add your `MaterialButton` inside that layout with `width to wrap_content`

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01' mdc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57237630/7254873

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code snippet you have in your original question is correct. This has been identified as a bug and will be fixed in the upcoming release.

Comment: Bug fixed in the version '28.0.0-rc01'

Answer (score 8):

With the **Material Components** library just use the **`app:iconGravity="textStart"`** attribute:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/..."
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        ../>
```

[image]

If you want to cut the corners use the **`app:shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/..."
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/Button.Cut"
        ../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="Button.Cut" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">4dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use width to wrap_content so it matches your text. And layout_gravity instead of gravity to set the button its own gravity (and not its childs).

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_my_orders"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Try this code to set left padding of button to make it center.

```
 <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/material_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:text="CENTER"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_location_on_accent_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

**JAVA**

```
 final MaterialButton button = root_view.findViewById(R.id.material_button);
 button.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int width = button.getWidth();
            button.measure(0,0);
            int paddingleft = (width - button.getMeasuredWidth() + 50)/2; //50 drawable width
            button.setPadding(paddingleft,0,0,0);
        }
    });
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: **FYI** `app:additionalPaddingLeftForIcon="100dp"
        app:additionalPaddingRightForIcon="80dp"` is not available in `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01`

Comment: @NileshRathod i did not noticed that am using `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'` thanks for info.

Comment: @MuhammadakbarRafiqov see my updated answer will help you.