# How to center icon in a MaterialButton which has no text?

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android

I'm using the latest version of the `com.google.android.material:material` library (i.e. `1.1.0-alpha03`) and I have a `MaterialButton` defined with an icon and no text as follows:

I was hoping the `MaterialButton` would be rendered as a square with the icon centred within it but instead the `MaterialButton` is rendered as follows:

[image: MaterialButton with iconGravity value of start]

If I change the `iconGravity` value to `"textStart"` the `MaterialButton` is rendered as follows:

[image: MaterialButton with iconGravity value of textStart]

This is a slight improvement to the positioning of the icon but the icon is still a little off centre. If I change the `insetLeft`, `insetRight`, `insetTop` and `insetBottom` values to `0dp` the `MaterialButton` is rendered as follows:

[image]

This is an improvement to the shape of the button but the icon is still a little off centre.

Anyone know whether there's something further I can do to centre the icon within the `MaterialButton`?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633118/how-to-set-materialbutton-icon-to-the-center  I may recommend to use "textStart" and insetLeft=2dp (may be 1-4dp, so look what you've got while changes)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that thread out. I had seen that thread but it's not the same problem. That thread (from what I understood of it) was about centering the icon together with the text within the `MaterialButton`. I am trying to centre an icon which has no supporting text. I found my answer nonetheless. The missing attribute I needed was `app:iconPadding="0dp"`.

Comment: https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Found it. The attribute I was missing was `app:iconPadding="0dp"`.

So, from my experiments, the minimum attributes needed to create a square `MaterialButton` which has a centred icon and no text is the following:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:insetLeft="0dp"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetRight="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    app:icon="@drawable/icon_next"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
    app:iconPadding="0dp" />
```

These attributes produce a `MaterialButton` as follows:

[image: MaterialButton with square shape and centred icon]

Comment: It wouldn't work if icon is slightly bigger. Try with 50dp icon. I don't even know after what size it is broken.

Comment: @OleksandrAlbul Try `app:iconGravity="top"`. It will always center it regardless of the width.

Comment: Dynamically, I used `button.setIconGravity(MaterialButton.ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_START);`

Comment: `app:iconSize` and `app:iconTint` can be useful too.

Comment: It works even on Android 4.2.2, cool!

Answer (score 66):

Change iconGravity to textStart and iconPadding to 0dp

```
    app:iconPadding="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
```

Answer (score 14):

## Use `Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton` style

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_power_settings_new_24"
    app:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorButtonNormal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Add this style to the button

```
<Button style="@style/Widget.App.Button.IconOnly"/>
```

then in `res/values/styles.xml` add the following

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button.IconOnly" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="iconPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
</style>
```

source: [https://material.io/components/buttons/android](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#implementing-an-icon-only-toggle-button)

Answer (score 2):

square button:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.Icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:iconGravity="textTop"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:cornerRadius="16dp"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#30000000"
        app:iconTint="@color/white"
        app:icon="@drawable/bag"/>
```

circle :

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:cornerRadius="20dp"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconPadding="0dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:insetLeft="0dp"
            android:insetRight="0dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:iconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:icon="@drawable/send"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also an `Icon` version of the material style on your button. For filled buttons like you are using, you could set the style to `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried this but I've found it's still necessary to set the `insetLeft`, `insetTop`, `insetRight`, `insetBottom`, `iconGravity` and `iconPadding` attributes on the `MaterialButton` as described in my answer to get a square shape with a centred icon. If you can share an example of the attributes that you've used together with the style attribute and a screenshot of the result that would be handy!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `app:iconGravity="textStart"` stopped working after I updated `appcompat` to version `1.4.0`.
I now use `app:iconGravity="textTop"`

Answer (score 1):

using `Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon` style :

```xml
style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
app:iconGravity="textStart"
app:iconPadding="0dp"
android:padding="10dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this in code with:

```java
button.setIconPadding(0);
button.setPaddingRelative(0, 0, 0, 0);
button.setIconGravity(MaterialButton.ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_TOP);
```