# android material button icon center vertically

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I am trying to use the material components button with an icon, but the icon does not appear vertically centered. I want the phone icon centered vertically with the text.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/callButton"
                style="@style/PrimaryButtonRoundedCorner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin_medium"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin_large"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_margin_medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/call_kris_bodnar"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_phone"
                app:iconGravity="start"
                app:iconTint="@color/wireframe_dark_gray"/>


<style name="PrimaryButtonRoundedCorner" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon">
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_height</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="cornerRadius">@dimen/button_corner_radius</item>s
    </style>
```

**Vector drawable xml.**

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#4A4A4A" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M3.2178,8.2228C4.4978,11.21 6.56,13.6483 9.0756,15.1789L11.0311,12.8567C11.2711,12.5717 11.6267,12.4767 11.9378,12.6033C12.9333,12.9939 14.0089,13.205 15.1111,13.205C15.6,13.205 16,13.68 16,14.2606L16,17.9444C16,18.525 15.6,19 15.1111,19C6.7644,19 0,10.9672 0,1.0556C0,0.475 0.4,0 0.8889,0L4,0C4.4889,0 4.8889,0.475 4.8889,1.0556C4.8889,2.375 5.0667,3.6417 5.3956,4.8239C5.4933,5.1933 5.4222,5.605 5.1733,5.9006L3.2178,8.2228L3.2178,8.2228Z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

I am using version `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06"`

[image]

Any idea?
Many thanks

Comment: Could you post the phone drawable’s XML?

Comment: @Edric sorry for the delay, I Have added the vector drawable xml. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713480/4088135

Answer (score 0):

i don't know much about the MaterialButton , i have never used it before but assuming it is still a button, add drawable padding

```
       android:drawablePadding="8dp"
```